# Python PEG Grammar Notation

Tags: python, grammar, ebnf, peg

Here is a snippet from the new python [PEG grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

```
# type_expressions allow */** but ignore them
type_expressions:
    | ','.expression+ ',' '*' expression ',' '**' expression 
    | ','.expression+ ',' '*' expression 
    | ','.expression+ ',' '**' expression 
    | '*' expression ',' '**' expression 
    | '*' expression 
    | '**' expression 
    | ','.expression+
```

I don't understand what the dotted notation `','.expression+` means here? How do i read this? A python snippet matching it would be welcome.

Considering the context:

```
func_type: '(' [type_expressions] ')' '->' expression NEWLINE* ENDMARKER
```

It seems like `type_expressions` are function arguments, but I don't see how? How does it match multiple arguments?

The Docs state the following:

> The notation is a mixture of EBNF and PEG. In particular, & followed by a symbol, token or parenthesized group indicates a positive lookahead (i.e., is required to match but not consumed), while ! indicates a negative lookahead (i.e., is required *not* to match). We use the | separator to mean PEG’s “ordered choice” (written as / in traditional PEG grammars).

I checked both the EBNF and PEG wikipedia page, and the only thing I found is that the dot is a terminator symbol according to [conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Conventions). But that is confusing because semi colon is also a terminator symbol and in this context it doesn't seem like a terminator symbol.

Comment: I believe it's a shortcut for grouping. I.e. `','.expression+`  is the same as `(',' expression)+`. You always see the dot with the Kleene operator. I don't think spaces around the dot matter, and personally I think it might improve in readability, but the don't use the in the Python grammar.

Comment: @kaby76 Hmm, that kind of makes sense, but if that's the case then it seems like every `type_expression` must start with `,` or `*` which doesn't make sense?

Comment: You are right. `a.b+` = `b (a b)*`. E.g., `','.NAME+` in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4e4d35d3325fb1e05dad43bd1ec73f14c3c5dc0a/Grammar/python.gram#L115) vs [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4e4d35d3325fb1e05dad43bd1ec73f14c3c5dc0a/Grammar/Grammar#L110). The only way to know for sure is to read the damn code for the parser generator and generated parser. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Tools/peg_generator/pegen/metagrammar.gram#L100

Comment: The notation is explained [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/#s-e).

Comment: Thanks, you can add it as an answer if you want. I will accept it.